# Polynomial array representation not working properly

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a polynomial class where the polynomials are represented by an array of coefficient/exponent pairs. I've created the add method to add two polynomials, but instead my values gets duplicated.

```
public class Poly{


private static class Pair{

int coeff;
int exponent;

private Pair(){

this.coeff=coeff;
this.exponent=exponent;
 }

private Pair(int coef, int exp){

exponent = exp;
coeff = coef;
 }

}

int count=2;
private Pair[] poly; //creates an Array of coefficient/exponent pairs

public Poly(){

poly = new Pair[count];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
poly[i] = new Pair(0,0);
 }

}


public Poly(int coeff1, int exp){

int i=0;
poly = new Pair[count];
for(i=0; i<count; i++){
poly[i]= new Pair(coeff1, exp);
}

count++;
}

private Poly (int exp) {

poly = new Pair[exp+1];
   poly[0].exponent = exp;
   poly[0].coeff=1;

}


**public Poly add(Poly q){**
Poly result = new Poly();
int j=0;

while(j<poly.length){

    for(int i=0; i<q.poly.length; i++){

        if(poly[j].exponent==q.poly[i].exponent){
        result.poly[j].coeff= poly[j].coeff+q.poly[i].coeff;
        result.poly[j].exponent =poly[j].exponent;
        }
        else if(poly[j].exponent!=q.poly[i].exponent && i<q.poly.length){
        result.poly[j].coeff= q.poly[i].coeff;
        result.poly[j].exponent =q.poly[i].exponent;
        }

        else if(poly[j].exponent!=q.poly[i].exponent && i==q.poly.length-1){
        result.poly[j].coeff= poly[j].coeff;
        result.poly[j].exponent =poly[j].exponent;
        }

    }
    j++;
}
return result;
}





public String toString(){

String str = "";

for(int i=0; i<poly.length; i++){

    if(poly[i].coeff==0){
        str+="";
    }

    else{
    str+="+" +poly[i].coeff +"x^"+poly[i].exponent;
}
}
return str;
}


}
```

I'm trying to get a value as the sum of two polynomials (5x^9) & (3x^8) to return 5x^9+3x^8

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Poly a =new Poly(5,9);
Poly b =new Poly(3,8);

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println("the sum of the poly is: " +ab);
```

}

the output is

```
a=+5x^9+5x^9
b=+3x^8+3x^8
the sum of the poly is: +3x^8+3x^8
```

Comment: Please isolate the problem more. You posted a lot of source code. Most of this code is not necessary to show the problem and it simply costs time and energy for the readers to understand what the important parts are.

Comment: Please show the output, and explain what about the output you do NOT expect.

Comment: Again here, do not do more than one calculation with output. Do just the one which doesn't work accordingly to your expectations.

Comment: Could you post the output as well?

Comment: I've included the output. the output i'm trying to get is the sum of the two polynomials

Answer (score 1):

Your code is painful to read, you should format it.  Spaces are cheap, don't be stingy with them.  Don't just stick all the functions along the left margin; indent them so their position and scope are obvious.

The `count` variable is redundant.  Just use `poly.length` instead.

For now, `Poly.sub(x)` should just be implemented as `return add(minus(x));`.  It's more inefficient but simple and obviously correct.

How are you deciding to set the `Poly[]` array sizes?  You're using `count` to set them, which can be wrong.  Maybe you should use `java.util.ArrayList<Pair>` instead, and just `add()` to them.   I don't understand how you're not getting array-out-of-bounds exceptions all over the place.

`mult()` is not properly multiplying polynomials.  How do you coalesce product terms with the same exponent?

Make a function `Poly Poly.pairMult(Pair)`, then re-implement `mult()` using `pairMult()` and `add`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Poly a = new Poly( 5, 9 );
System.out.println( a );
```

Gives

```
+5x^9+5x^9
```

I assume you only want `+5x^9` to be output?

There's a loop in your `toString()` which will iterate `count` times, `count` is initialized to 2.